# Назначение одного и того же медиафайла WordPress разным записям одновременно

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Всем здравствуйте.
Ваяю интернет-каталог на WordPress + WooCommerce, столкнулся с проблемой.
Задачка со звездочкой. В карточке товара нужны дополнительные поля, а именно: "Фото до", "Фото после" и "Чертежи". Причем сделать это нужно так, чтобы при добавлении фото в одно из полей, можно было проставить галки для ОДНОВРЕМЕННОГО добавления ЭТОГО ЖЕ ФОТО в разные галереи (отдельный плагин) и в один из разделов портфолио (тоже отдельный плагин).
Перебрал всевозможные плагины, ничего даже и близко похожего не нашел.
Подскажите, если есть, готовое решение, даже платное, даже отдаленно напоминающее, допилю ручками, написать с нуля не умею((
Буду признателен за любую наводку.
Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос закрыт, решено своими силами.
Решил установкой плагина ACF (Advanced Custom Fields), картинки вывел циклом с рядом проверок, по ID, типу поста и имени кастомного поля

Comment: если Вы самостоятельно решили сой вопрос - опубликуйте решение. Оно может пригодиться другим пользователям, столкнувшимся с этой же проблемой.